# PHP script to draw a spiral?

Tags: php, algorithm, drawing, spiral

Does anybody have a PHP (or other language) script for drawing a spiral. A simple ([Archimedean spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral)) would be just fine. Of course the principle is simple but coding it in SVG or GD would take some time, so I wonder if somebody has one ready :-)

Comment: Have you tried google?  I found an example in the first few search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page: [Using GD (imagearc) and PHP to draw spirals](http://php5unleashed.atw.hu/ch27lev1sec2.html) (Listing 27.3)